# IRC Client - channel latitude and longitude details

Tags: irc

Is there a way to retrieve latitude and longitude details of IRC channel so that I can locate the same on Map.

Thanks.

Comment: IRC channels do not have a location. Do you mean if you can find the location of the server where the IRC daemon is running? In that case only by using the server's IP address and some geolocation library.

Comment: What location are you actually asking for? The location of the server that you're connecting to? The location of the people in the channel? There's really no physical "location" for an IRC channel.

Comment: @evan in fact I am looking for the location of the people in the channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the locations of the people in the channel, you could simply look at their hostname - names on IRC are made up of a nickname, a username, and a hostname in the format nickname!username@hostname.

The hostname could be one of three things - an IP address, a DNS name, or a "cloak". You could use a DNS client to convert the hostname into an IP address, and then with the IP addresses you could use an IP geolocation tool (such as [ipinfodb.com](http://ipinfodb.com) which has a nice free API), and retrieve the latitude and longtitude of each user.

If the hostname is a cloak, and the format of this varies between networks, then there's no way (unless you have advanced privileges on the IRC network) to get the real IP/hostname (and hence location) of that user.

Answer (score 1):

Radoslaw Zielinski (radek at pld-linux dot org) wrote a Perl script for geolocation of nicknames in the XChat IRC client:

> I wrote a simple plugin to look up the IP address in the [Maxmind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity) GeoIP lookup database, you can find it here: [xchat-geo.pl](http://radek.cc/xchat-geo.pl).  See “perldoc xchat-geo.pl” for the installation instructions.
>
> **Usage:**
>   `/geo some_nickname`
>
> **Output:**
>   [17:33] ==> some_nickname | US San Francisco CA 37.7525 -122.3194  n=somenick@some.host

Original blog post: www.radek.cc/2009/09/06/irc-xchat-geolocation-plugin/

It requires that you install:

- Perl
- one of the Maxmind GeoIP databases (some are free)
- the Maxmind Geo::IP module (its API for Perl)
- XChat with a Perl scripting interface plugin

xchat-geo.pl, retrieved 2012-03-06:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Geo::IP ();

our $VERSION = '0.04';

=head1 NAME

xchat-geo.pl - geolocation plugin for xchat

=head1 SYNOPSIS

  perl -MCPAN -e 'install Geo::IP'
  chmod +x xchat-geo.pl
  mv xchat-geo.pl ~/.xchat/

  # in xchat
  /unload .xchat/xchat-geo.pl
  /load   .xchat/xchat-geo.pl
  /geo some-nickname

=head1 DESCRIPTION

Usage:
/geo some_nickname
[17:33] ==> some_nickname | US San Francisco CA 37.7525 -122.3194
n=somenick@some.host

Provides a single C</geo> command, which attempts to lookup the IP address in
the maxmind GeoIP database.

Requires the Geo::IP module to be installed, along with the GeoIP City (or its
free GeoLite counterpart); see L<http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location> and
L<http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity>.

On my machine, the installed databases look like this:

  $ ls -l /usr/share/GeoIP
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       15 Sep  6 16:54 GeoIPCity.dat -> GeoLiteCity.dat
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   877738 Sep  6 16:25 GeoIP.dat
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 27711885 Sep  6 16:31 GeoLiteCity.dat

Released 2009-09-06

=head1 AUTHOR

Radoslaw Zielinski E<lt>radek@pld-linux.orgE<gt>
http://radek.cc/2009/09/06/irc-xchat-geolocation-plugin/

=head1 LICENSE

GPL v3

=cut


our $geo = Geo::IP->open_type( Geo::IP::GEOIP_CITY_EDITION_REV1 ) # Geo::IP::GEOIP_STANDARD
    or die "can't load the GeoIP database";

Xchat::print('xchat geo starting');
Xchat::register( 'xchat geo', $VERSION, 'geo location for xchat', \&unload );

Xchat::hook_print( 'Join', \&Join, );
Xchat::hook_command( 'geo', sub { geo(@_); Xchat::EAT_ALL; }, );

# for debugging / plugin development
#Xchat::hook_command( 'xev', sub { eval $_[1][0]; Xchat::EAT_ALL; }, );

sub Join {
    my ( $user, $channel, $host ) = @{ $_[0] };
    my $r = record_from_ihost($host);
    Xchat::printf( "-\x0311->\x03\t\x02%s \x0f\x0314(\x0311%s\x0314) \x03has joined %s [\x0308%s\x0f]",
        $user, $host, $channel,
        $r && ref $r
        ? join( ', ', map { defined $_ ? $_ : '' } $r->country_code, $r->city, $r->region, $r->postal_code, )
        : '' );
    return Xchat::EAT_XCHAT;
}

# /geo some_nickname
sub geo {
    my ($cmd) = @_;
    defined $cmd->[1] && length $cmd->[1]
      or return Xchat::print('nick?');
    my $user = Xchat::user_info( $cmd->[1] )
      or return Xchat::print("no such nick $cmd->[1]");
    my $r = record_from_ihost( $user->{host} )
      or return;
    return ref $r
      ? Xchat::print(
        ' ==> ' . join "\t", $user->{nick}, $r->country_code, $r->city, $r->region,
        $r->latitude,        $r->longitude, $r->postal_code,  $user->{host}
      )
      : Xchat::print($r);
}

# input: nick and hostname, as reported by xchat
# - n=user@hostname
# - n=user@IP.address
# - n=user@some/freenode/cloak  (useless)
# output: a string with error message or a Geo::IP record
sub record_from_ihost {
    my $ihost = shift
      or return;
    ( my $nick = $ihost ) =~ s/^.=|\@.*//g;
    $ihost =~ /^ [^@]* \@ (?: ((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\.\d{1,3}) | ([a-zA-Z\d_-]+\.[.a-zA-Z\d_-]+) ) (?: \s.* )? $/x
      or return "no useful host for <$nick> -- $ihost";
    my $r = ( $1 ? $geo->record_by_ip($1) : $geo->record_by_name($2) )
      or return "no useful geo info for <$nick> -- $ihost " . ( $1 ? "1: $1" : "2: $2" );
    return $r;
}

sub unload {
    undef $geo;
    Xchat::print('xchat geo exiting');
}

# vim: ts=4 sw=4 noet
```